# Linking allegro 5 on debian

Tags: linux, linker, allegro

I followed this guide: http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Debian_and_Allegro_5
Everything went smooth, and I have /usr/include/allegro5 and allegro lirary files in /usr/lib

When I compile simple program, includes are resolved correctly, but I have problem with linking.

pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 returns "-lallegro".

When I put -lallegro (or `pkg-config --libs allegro-50`) into the makefile, I get message
"Cannot find -lallegro"

Makefile:
    g++ -static -O2 $(INCLUDES) $(SRC) -otest -D USE_THREADS -lboost_thread -lpthread -L/usr/lib/ `pkg-config --libs --cflags allegro-5.0`

Answer (score 0):

If `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0` is returning the `-lallegro` and the library exists in `/usr/lib`, then you probably just need to run `sudo ldconfig`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, when I run as root:
ldconfig | grep allegro, the output is:
        liballegro_ttf.so.5.0 -> liballegro_ttf.so.5.0.6
        liballegro_color.so.5.0 -> liballegro_color.so.5.0.6
        (etc for other libraries, comment size is limited)
I'm not very experienced linux user, so I'm probably missing something simple as the -lallegro still doesn't work